# responsive naviagtion buttons

Tags: html, button, responsive-design

I have created a navigation section for my website using buttons. It looks fine, but when I minimize the window, the buttons stack up on each other and begin to overlap. Is there any way I can make them more responsive, so that perhaps they show underneath each other when the window is mininized? Thanks for any suggestions :)

```
    <nav>

        <div class="nav">
            <a href="index.html" class ="button">Home</a>
            <a href="about.html" class ="button">Rooms</a>      
            <a href="Contact.html" class ="button">Contact</a>
            <a href="Testimonials.html"" class ="button">Testimonials</a>
            <a href="FAQ's.html" class ="button">FAQ's</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

CSS

```
.nav {

    background-color: #A0BBF3;
    float: center;
    display: block;
    color: #0F49C5;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1px 2px;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-size: 1.1em;

}


.nav a:hover {
    background-color: #0F49C5;
    color: #A0BBF3;

}
    .button {
      text-decoration: none;
      background-color: #4E7DE0;
      color: #A0BBF3;
      padding: 4px 8px 4px 8px;
      border-top: 2px solid #7298E9;
      border-right: 2px solid #2D63D4;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #2D63D4;
      border-left: 2px solid #7298E9;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to try using flexbox

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try using  `Bootstrap 4` classes for making your page responsive.
Bootstrap uses a grid system and flexbox display using which you can easily set media queries. 
You can set the value at which your page breaks.

Eg:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2">
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this css to `.nav` to align the items the way you want.

```
justify-content: center!important;
display: flex!important;
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/Ww1bAiQKLU